# Access a singleton across multiple modules

Tags: scope, rust, singleton

I am trying to use the lazy_static crate to create a singleton and use it in a different module. Is that possible or even recommended? I'm still learning how Rust programs should be structured and have been making every file its own module.

I have the following in main.rs and I can access its values

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref GAMEDATA: gamedata::data::GameDataS =
        gamedata::data::load_data("./src/assets/data.json".to_string());
}

fn main() {
    println!("data{}", GAMEDATA.width);
}
```

When trying to access `GAMEDATA` in a different module, I get

> not found in this scope

for example in a module called `game`

```
pub struct Game {}
impl Game {
    println!("data{}", GAMEDATA.width);
}
```

Is it possible to make a global variable across all modules? Is there some other way I should be thinking about it? Perhaps not using modules as often?

Comment: If you're willing to make a game, did you see a framework like amethyst?

Comment: Yeah I saw it. I want to make my own engine using sdl. I'm just doing 2d stuff right now.

Comment: Your code **isn't valid Rust syntax** and does not produce the error you say it does. Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Also, this question has *nothing* to do with `lazy_static`; you'd have the same problem for *any* symbol at the root of your crate.

Answer (score 3):

If your static variable is in another non-parent module, your problem seems to be a missing `pub` modifier before `static`. Also, as others pointed out, the code in which you use the variable (the `impl` block) is not valid Rust syntax.

Besides that, you will need to import the static variable with `use` (E.g. `use GAMEDATA;`), see [Quan Brew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108194/155423).

However, I want to discuss about the use of static and singleton pattern in Rust.

## Static variables in Rust

In Rust we generally avoid static variables. In most cases they could be replaced with a proper constant via `const`. Because static variables may be shared between threads, having them with external mutability is `unsafe` in Rust. This is why you cannot have external mutability with lazy_static.

Although statics with external mutability do have their uses, they are kind of specific, should be justified and avoided otherwise. Interior mutability, as described in [this section of the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) is not even allowed to be shared among threads.

## Singleton Pattern in Rust

I don't think it is a good idea to use static to have singleton pattern. This pattern is not common in Rust. We generally pass all mutable things as arguments.

## Solutions if you need immutable data

1. Make it a constant with `const`.
2. If there is too much data, use `static`.
3. If you need non-constant initialization, you can keep lazy_static.

## Solutions if you need to mutate data

1. Put your singleton into a `Mutex` or another lock. This will ensure correct concurrent accesses.
2. Make it thread local with [thread_local macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html) + [inner mutability with RefCell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html)
3. Give up the "singleton pattern" idea and pass the structure via arguments (recommended).

Comment: This is great advice but doesn’t actually solve the problem

Comment: What happened? What did you try to do and what was the outcome?

Comment: It says it says no GAMEDATA in root when trying Brews solution. I believe because the module is in a different file. I'm about to start working on it again and if I can't figure it out I will edit my question with a git hub example or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need `use` to import `GAMEDATA` into the current scope, as described in the [modules section in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch07-00-modules.html).

Example code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d560b772bf82af8b88fea3f70a1738d7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static; // 1.1.0

lazy_static! {
    static ref GAMEDATA: String = "hello".to_string();
}

mod foo {
    use GAMEDATA;
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("{}", *GAMEDATA);
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo::bar();
}
```

However, the singleton pattern is not recommended in Rust. For beginners in the learning phase, you'd best avoid singletons. (see [bzim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108202/155423))

Comment: I feel like this is close, but now it says no GAMEDATA in root. Perhaps because these are in different files with a lib.rs. IS there a way to address it from a different file?